# Signing transactions using metamask provider

Tags: metamask

I would like to sign a transaction using the metamask provider so that the transaction can be sent later as a raw transaction. Is there any way to implement this in code? I believe that a metamask pop up would appear for the user to confirm signing the transaction[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the transaction object and pass in the data to Metamask for signature via `eth_sign`. You can refer [docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#signing-data-with-metamask) for more info.

Comment: Would provider.signTransaction work with ethers? Also web3?. I have some difficulty differentiating with eth_sign and the provider.signTransaction these would do the same thing?